# Transform a "call" object into a function in R

Tags: r, function, object, derivative

From a derivation I get a "call" object as seen in the code snippet. I want to transform this into a function with arguments but I can't figure out how to get it right. It returns just the call object.

```
someDeriv <- D(expression(a * x^2 + x), "x")
someDeriv
#returns: a * (2 * x) + 1
class(someDeriv)
#returns: "call"

#here comes the important part
fn <- as.function(alist(a=,x=,someDeriv))

fn(a=1, x=2)
#returns: a * (2 * x) + 1
#should return: 5
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`alist` quotes its arguments, so when you pass names of variables, their values aren't substituted in the returned list. This means that `alist(a =, x =, someDeriv)` is *not* equivalent to `alist(a =, x =, a * (2 * x) + 1)`.

```r
someDeriv <- D(expression(a * x^2 + x), "x")
l1 <- alist(a =, x =, someDeriv)
l1
```

```
$a


$x


[[3]]
someDeriv
```

```r
l2 <- alist(a =, x =, a + (2 * x) + 1)
l2
```

```
$a


$x


[[3]]
a + (2 * x) + 1
```

Your function `fn` is actually defined as:

```r
fn <- as.function(l1)
fn
```

```
function (a, x) 
someDeriv
```

No matter what values you pass for `a` and `x`, `fn` returns the value of `someDeriv`, which in your global environment is the call `a * (2 * x) + 1`.

To get the behaviour you want, you can do this:

```r
l3 <- c(alist(a =, x =), list(someDeriv))
l3
```

```
$a


$x


[[3]]
a * (2 * x) + 1
```

```r
fn <- as.function(l3)
fn(a = 1, x = 2)
```

```
[1] 5
```